# WebSockets with SSL on Heroku - issues in Chrome and FireFox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, firefox, heroku, websocket

I have a chat application hosted on Heroku that is using WebSockets. The app is Rails 4.0.1 and Ruby 2.0.0 and is using the gem 'websocket-rails'.

The application was working fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox when I was using standard http://. Then today I added SSL endpoint on Heroku. Now, the app works fine in Safari, but in Chrome and Firefox it will take > 1 minute to load any page (even just a static page). It is getting hung up on something (I'm guessing the WebSocket connection) but I am having a hard time debugging the root problem. Any ideas or things to try would be greatly appreciated.

The app is: http://www.chat-correct.com. If you try it in Safari it should load the pages relatively fast, but if you try it in Chrome or Firefox you will see that it hangs.

I am using:
Safari Version 6.1 (8537.71)
Chrome Version 31.0.1650.39 beta
Firefox Version 22

**UPDATE**

I have narrowed the issue down and it seems to be with using the thin web server:
Thin web server (v1.6.1 codename Death Proof)

If I switch the app to WEBrick, the Chrome/Firefox issue disappears. However, the web socket-rails gem doesn't work with WEBrick and only seems to support only event machine based web servers (thus Unicorn/Puma is out of the question).

Answer (score 0):

Try Rainbows!.  http://rainbows.rubyforge.org/  It is based on unicorn and also can be configured to use EventMachine for network concurrency.  Though to be fair, I ran into your question because I have a similar issue on rainbows.  Anyway, I have a slightly different setup so it may not be an issue for you.